# Explorer Shell Extension Existing Column

Tags: windows, winapi, shell-extensions

[image: Sample explorer snapshot]

I want to use existing columns (Example: Status Column) available in Explorer to display status of files. I have read that we can't create custom column on Vista and upper OS. How can we read and modify existing columns?

Comment: You cannot modify existing columns.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Is it possible to use Status column if I add corresponding property to files? And how can I get the corresponding property name / ID for Status?